# Feature id generation in spatial database

Tags: geoserver

I am using a view

```sql
SELECT a.id,
    c.nombre AS "UEB",
    b.nombre AS "Unidad",
    a.geom
   FROM genetica.multimedia a,
    genetica.unidad b,
    genetica.ueb c
  WHERE a.iduni = b.iduni AND b.idueb = c.idueb;
```

for generate a layer on GeoServer but it needs an id field for linking to JSON and XML files. I created a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE genetica.gt_pk_metadata
(
  table_schema character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  table_name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column_idx integer,
  pk_policy character varying(32),
  pk_sequence character varying(64),
  CONSTRAINT pk_table PRIMARY KEY (table_schema, table_name, pk_column),
  CONSTRAINT unique_table UNIQUE (table_schema, table_name, pk_column)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and I filled with data about the view, but GeoServer does not work with that. Any suggestions?

---

I found this:
From my web search, the last message seems common among WFS-T users. So I clicked through several pages, tutorials and message boards (including this one) to find a solution. It seemed, that I needed a Primary Key Metadata table to get updatable views. So I added one with the name gt_pk_metadata_table to my database:
[image]
Then I referenced that table in my GeoServer data store (under "Primary key metadata table") and saved. Unfortunately, .....

1. Where do I create the Primary Key Metadata table?
2. How do I reference that table in my Geoserver data store?

Comment: If you work on POSTGRES, you can add an ID field with the type 'SERIAL' and it will be filled automatically every time you add a feature

Comment: I found the answer to this in https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking for a 'dummy' OBJECTID column, add this to your select in your view.

Below the row_number() function is used with the sorting on the c.nombre column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW AS (

SELECT 
    row_number() over(order by c.nombre) as OBJECTID, 
    a.id,
    c.nombre AS "UEB",
    b.nombre AS "Unidad",
    a.geom
   FROM genetica.multimedia a,
    genetica.unidad b,
    genetica.ueb c
  WHERE a.iduni = b.iduni AND b.idueb = c.idueb

);
```

Comment: an `order by` clause should (must!) be included in the `over()` statement to maintain the row-to-id integrity so the same feature is always associated to the same ID (when displaying it or when querying its attributes)

Comment: @JGH we always try to have an order by but we have used it without and never had an issue... i have seen a few threads that state it works, but others that show the problem you have described. i'll modify the answer just to avoid any pitfalls with this...